# Automapper profiles not working

Tags: c#, automapper

Does anyone know why this works:

```
Mapper.Configuration.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Foo");
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
```

But this doesn't:

```
Mapper.CreateProfile("FooPrefix").RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Foo");
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
      .WithProfile("FooPrefix");
```

?

Comment: This is a good question however time passed 2016 I still can't find an answer. this CreateProfile() method seems does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this question is quite old now, I thought it would be useful to answer it given I spent ages trying to get profiles to work.

Although there are a bunch of ways to configure profiles, it seems that the only way what I could get it to work was as follows:

```
public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        ReplaceMemberName("Z", "A");
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>(); // Notice this is CreateMap, NOT Mapper.CreateMap...
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}
```

Then, set up the profile in your config:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<ExampleProfile>());
```

Given the Source and Destination classes as follows:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Zabc { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Aabc { get; set; }
}
```

This should now work:

```
var source = new Source { Zabc = "source" };
var dest = Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
Assert.AreEqual(source.Zabc, dest.Aabc);
```

Comment: I'm not working with C# at the moment, so will take me a bit of time to verify the answer. I'll accept "tentatively", if you will :-)

Comment: Hey - no worries. I mainly put it up because this answer appears in search results, so I'll be able to find it again :)

Answer (score 2):

Profile names are different. You use FooxPrefix when creating the profile and then use FooPrefix when creating the map.

Comment: The error was just here on StackOverflow when I wrote a quick "pseudo-code" example. It doesn't work with the correct prefix.